# Vue.http causes error when using typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

so I've just changed my project from js to typescript, and I have the following code that sets up vue resouce :-

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

however typescript throws an error on the `.http`.  Is there a standard way to fix this? Is there a way to let typescript know it exists?

In other files they access `Vue.http` as well but only get at http by importing Vue

The error is :-

[image]

or in the compiler

[image]

Comment: Are you still importing `Vue`?

Comment: yes, updated code...

Comment: What is the verbatim error message?

Comment: @stealththeninja screen shots of the errors....

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js includes type definitions in the project ([`types/vue.d.ts`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/master/types/vue.d.ts)) but it would seem VueResource does not yet. To get started, I think creating a custom `vue-resource.d.ts` (or `vue-resource.types.ts` and import it) with definitions that extend Vue's types and adding it to your project could resolve the issue.